# Where can I store the Endpoint configuration when calling a WS from a DLL?

Tags: .net, wcf, dll

I have a set of services, some of them will be Web Services, some will be stored in DLLs, and so on. I would like to create a framework so it is transparent for the caller if he is calling a WS, DLL or something else.

The problem is, if I add a Web Reference in my DLL project, once I add it as a reference in other project (say Project A) and start it, the configuration file  which will be used will be Project A's App.config, which has no information about the WebService endpoint and so on.
An easy way to solve it is copying the configuration section to Project A's App.config, but then the transparency would break.

Is there any other way to store it easily? 
I could also create the endpoint programatically, but I would have to store all the info in the App.config information, so, at the end of the day, it would be the same as copying the config section....

This problem seems awkward, so maybe I am getting everything wrong.... Am I?

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know how I solved this problem:

It is possible to instantiate the proxy class passing only the binding and the EndpointAddress, this is what I've done:

```
client = new ContractClient(new NetMsmqBinding(NetMsmqSecurityMode.None), new EndpointAddress(new Uri(config.WebServiceAddress.Value)) );
```

Where config is an object which reads the App.config. (ConfigurationManager.GetSection for more information)